# Conditional curve fit with scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Let's say I want to fit a straight line to my data recorded with lights off. Now I accidentally left the lights on, and my data has a constant offset from datapoint 101 and onwards.

How can I fit this? I've tried to incorporate a condition for x, but I get the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Remember to uncomment the remainder of the code (to encounter the error).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = np.random.normal(0,0.1, 100)
d2 = np.random.normal(3,0.1, 100)

x = np.arange(0,200)
y = np.concatenate((d1,d2))

plt.plot(x, y)

# def line(x, a, b, offset):
#     if x < 101:
#         y = a * x + b
#     else:
#         y = (a * x + b) + offset
#     return y
# 
# popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(line, xdata = x, ydata = y)
# 
# plt.plot(x, line(x, *popt), color = "firebrick")
plt.show()
```

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: While Pavel's trick might work here. Be careful with more complex optimization-models. That trick invalidates (imho) assumptions of those solvers. An alternative would be an outer minimize_scalar loop with a manual curve-fit-like (manual because it's not that nice to fix params with curve_fit's API) inner-calculation where offset get's fixed.

Comment: Adding to this, I tried to combine two quite different functions in one, with conditionals for x, e.g. `return f(x) * (x => z) + g(x) * (x < z)`, and the errors turned out to be +/- infinity for all parameters. So you're completely right! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the standard trick would be to convert boolean condition to an integer factor:

```
def line(x, a, b, offset):
    return (a * x + b) + offset * (x>100)
```

Comment: Very useful trick! It easily works with several offset constants at once, for different ranges, if added as a new term with its own bool.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting that error is that `optimize` is calling your `line` function by passing it an `array` of values, not just a single value. To fix this issue, your `line` function must me able to handle an array of values. Fortunately, `numpy` has a function to help you.

```
def line(x, a, b, offset):
    return np.piecewise(x, 
                        [x < 101, x >= 101],
                        [lambda x: a * x + b, lambda x: a * x + b + offset])
```

I should note that it still does not converge but that is a different issue.